# Ubuntu 14.04 freezes after staying idle/KDE freezes

Tags: 12.04, 14.04, ati, kubuntu, kde

I recently upgraded to Ubuntu 14.04 from 12.04.

Before updating I was warned that my graphics driver AMD Radeon HD 7600M series might not be supported/out of date. I updated the system anyhow and faced no problems until I countered the following problem(s).

1. 14.04 Works fine. When I lock screen on purpose then too I can activate screen and log back in. But if i leave my desk and the computer autolocks then I cannot enter. I just get the password screen and everything else is stuck. I cannot even move the mouse. I cannot open the terminal either. Keyboard is stuck. My only option is to force restart.
2. On reading certain forums I got the idea that maybe the Unity desktop might be creating problems, so I downloaded another desktop client, KUBUNTU. Which incidentally I loved. But here too I face the same problem. The only difference here is that at least I can move my mouse. Everything else is as described in point no 1.
3. On keeping KDE as the default desktop environment, I get stuck at the startup screen wherein it shows 5 icons. On double clicking it everything else turns black. But interestingly the mouse works and the right click even shows some options. But I cannot see the desktop.

So are there any options that I have so that I can work with Ubuntu 14.04 on my laptop.

Any help is appreciated.

Regards,
Debayan

Comment: I happened to see this post when searching for drivers for ATI cards. Here, you don't mention your gpu driver, have you tried changing it? But given that it is only when sleeping, I would think its not the driver. Have you messed with the settings for when it autolocks? Maybe just disable autolocking...

Comment: My GPU driver is Intel HD graphics 4000. How do I change it? Sorry if I sound like a noob :-p I haven't done anything with the autolocks yet, but I do not want to disable it since it will use up a lot of battery otherwise. That will be my last option.

Comment: Ha we were all noobs once :-) ATI using Intel drivers? Seems strange. I have a Radeon 7560D gpu and found this site (http://support.amd.com/en-us/download) to download the driver, but haven't installed, pls be careful messing with gpu drivers as you might end up with a blank screen. Still, i wonder with this behavior if it would be the driver at all.

Comment: Did you check your drivers in System Settings > Device drivers? The ATI driver is called fglrx, I have got fglrx, an updated flgrx, and a generic xserver-xorg-video-ati driver. What do you have in your list? I don't know why you would have an intel driver for your ATI gpu

Comment: Hi. Just an update. I checked the device drivers. I had the fglrx driver selected. I then selected the xserver-xorg driver and the problem was fixed (At least till now). So does that mean that it cannot run proprietary drivers? For me it's ok but just wanted to ask. I will mark the question as solved in a short while.

Comment: You can probably run the newest driver without a problem using that link i gave you, and usually in the default dialog it has flgrx and something like flgrx-updates which means it is the newest stable version. So you may have been using the basic one rather than updated one. So I think you can still use the proprietary drivers if you want, its just whatever the default one wasn't working for you.

Comment: Just to update you as well, I installed the newest driver without a problem and now the resolution looks better, but I notice that in the dialog now I can't do anything, all the options are greyed out. So I hope I dont have the change this one haha. Glad to hear you fixed the problem.